# Problem with table captions

Tags: labels

I have a problem with my table captions. In my document, the counter for Table sticks to the label in the caption. There should be a space separating the two! The peculiar thing is that I don't have this problem with my figure captions.
Here is the code I used for caption:

```
\usepackage[format=hang,labelsep=colon,labelfont=bf,textfont=it]{caption}
```

[image]

However for Figures I get this:

[image]

The document class is a customized format for my university. If everything is fine with my code, where should I look for the problem? In the .cls class file? If so, I have no idea how to interpret those lines of code in the class file!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should use show the code that produces this output -- a screen shot alone isn't helpful here

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The screenshot you've provided shows (at least) three significant changes from the default settings: (i) The word "Table" and associated number are in bold, (ii) the caption itself is in italics, and (iii) there's no space between "Table" and the associated number. Such changes don't happen all by themselves: Your document must contain one or more instructions that bring about these changes. Please tell us which document class you use, and also if you use any packages or have set up code of your own to modify the captions of `table` environments.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks for your comments :-)

Comment: @Mico thanks for your comment. I edited my code and added some information.

Comment: @AmirHamed: That `code` line is not sufficient. I've I use that I don' get the error you have.

Comment: If you have a `class` file for your template most likely is there... or a customized package to move things around.  Try looking into the custom your-university-exclusive packages and styles (.sty files)